# Prestashop mail subject special character issue

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

My customer is getting mail from my store with special characters on the mail subject

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Goto Classes/Mail.php
- find `Tools::safeOutput` and remove it, this function will convert all the special characters to html entity.
- Save the file
- Goto Backoffice->Advance->Performance->Clear Cache

[image]